# QGIS 2.6: GPX with 1546 records only reads 230

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.6

I have a gpx with 1546 waypoints. But: only 230 waypoints are read in QGIS 2.6 (using "add vector layer"), the rest is skipped. Can't understand why. File structure seems ok since the first 230 waypoints are read.

Comment: Could you share the file?

Comment: Do you get more if you use the GPS Tool for import from disk?

Answer (score 1):

I provide you with a link to [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110331/how-to-clean-edit-gpx-tracks-files-recorded-from-gps-device/110770#110770) to [How to clean/edit GPX (tracks) files recorded from GPS device?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110331)

The smart phone tool that I use sometimes creates incomplete files.  I have to add the last closing tag to the file in order to read the file.  I am guessing that JOSM validates the file structure before attempting to read the file into the application.  What if QGIS does not validate the complete file before reading?  It may be able to read in the first 230 point before encountering damage.  Can you validate the GPX?